# How to implement a meta-estimator with the scikit-learn API?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I would like to implement a simple wrapper / meta-estimator which is compatible with all of scikit-learn. It is hard to find a full description of what exactly I need.

The goal is to have a regressor which also learns a threshold to become a classifier. So I came up with:

```
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, ClassifierMixin, clone

class Thresholder(BaseEstimator, ClassifierMixin):
    def __init__(self, regressor):
        self.regressor = regressor
        # threshold_ does not get initialized in __init__ ??

    def fit(self, X, y, optimal_threshold):
        self.regressor = clone(self.regressor)    # is this required my sklearn??
        self.regressor.fit(X, y)

        y_raw = self.regressor.predict()
        self.threshold_ = optimal_threshold(y_raw)

    def predict(self, X):
        y_raw = self.regressor.predict(X)

        y = np.digitize(y_raw, [self.threshold_])

        return y
```

Is this implement the full API I need?

My main question is where to put the `threshold`. I want that it gets learned only once and can be re-used in subsequent `.fit` calls with new data without being readjusted. But with the current version it has to be retuned on every `.fit` call - which I do not want?

On the other hand, if I make it a fixed parameter `self.threshold` and pass it to `__init__`, then I'm not supposed to change it with the data?

How can I make a `threshold` parameter which can be tuned in one call of `.fit` and be fixed for subsequent `.fit` calls?

Comment: May I ask what's the reason for multiple `fit` calls? Is it some kind of online learning? Or is it due to cross-validation? or something else?

Comment: @ShihabShahriarKhan Only one fit with a certain collection of data (and certain test data stored in optimal_threshold) is good for determining the threshold. From then on, I wish to not retune the thresholds and only adjust the regressors for my data folds.

Comment: I may have misunderstood something...if you initialize `threshold_` as None in init, and check if it's value is set in `fit`, wouldn't it work? Kind of similar to `warm_start` param

Comment: Hard to say if it works, because sklearn has a certain API and functions like `clone` and other meta-estimators do some kind of magic behind the scenes. That's why I'd like to know the proper way with sklearn.

Comment: Why not just initialize `self.threshold = None` in the constructor and than an if statement - `if self.threshold is not None: self.threshold = optimal_threshold(y_raw)`? Although I think a better way would be adding a bool to the `fit` method indicating whatever or not to update the threshold

Answer (score 1):

[I actually wrote a blog post about this the other day](https://www.adithyabalaji.com/datascience/2021/04/08/Custom-Sklearn-Pipelines.html). I assume you are trying to build something similar to [`TransformedTargetRegressor`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.TransformedTargetRegressor.html) I would suggest taking a look at its source code to build something similar.

Your current implementation seems about right. As far as this concern goes:

> How can I make a threshold parameter which can be tuned in one call of `.fit` and be fixed for subsequent `.fit` calls?

I would suggest against that because `scikit-learn`'s API is based around the `fit` method re-fitting all tunable aspects of the model. There are two routes you can go here, either add a `**kwarg` to the fit that explicitly protects the `theshold` from updating or you can go with what [@rotem-tal suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58804308/how-to-implement-a-meta-estimator-with-the-scikit-learn-api#comment106624112_58804308). If you choose the latter, it might look something like this:

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, ClassifierMixin

def optimal_threshold(y_raw: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    return np.array([0.1, 0.5, 1])  # some implementation here

class Thresholder(BaseEstimator, ClassifierMixin):
    def __init__(self, regressor):
        self.regressor = regressor
        self.threshold = None

    def fit(self, X, y, optimal_threshold):
        # you don't need to clone the regressor
        self.regressor.fit(X, y)

        y_raw = self.regressor.predict()
        if self.threshold is None:
            self.threshold = optimal_threshold(y_raw)

    def predict(self, X):
        y_raw = self.regressor.predict(X)

        y = np.digitize(y_raw, [self.threshold_])

        return y
```

Comment: You need to follow the sklearn API otherwise things will not work. I just don't know how sklearn intended it. Your version will not work, because `clone` does not copy the `.threshold` attribute. However, `cross_validate` uses `clone` . Hence `cross_validate` will not work with my fixed threshold!?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, as I mentioned in the post, what you’re trying to do is non standard and likely won’t integrate well with the rest of the ecosystem (Pipelines and such) but it’s definitely possible.

Comment: I'm trying to find a way to make an estimator which fullfills the standard. Not everything which isn't in sklearn yet is non-standard automatically.

Comment: And the above will fit the API standard as far as programming interfaces go, give it a run. Though, “conceptually,” it doesn’t match the standard since threshold doesn’t update when `fit` is called.

Comment: If it doesn't work with key functions of sklearn, it does not fit the API standard. Making functions with similar names is not enough to follow the API as also the concept has to be fullfilled. This version of the code just doesn't work with `cross_validate` with a fixed threshold. I gave it a try and it just doesn't work for the explained reasons. `cross_validate` will refit the threshold for every fold.

Comment: From an ML perspective, it doesn’t make sense to hold threshold constant across folds. What sklearn under the hood is doing is cloning the structure of the estimator and running fit which loses your learned threshold from a prior fold. While I wouldn’t recommend it, a way around this might be to use a Python global value or a class variable which side steps the cloning issue.

Answer (score 0):

A totally legit question. Yes, to esure compatibility, you must

1. not do anything except params persisting in the ****init****
2. clone the inner estimator in the **fit**. Just use the underscore: `self.regressor_ = clone(self.regressor)`
3. to allow for more flexibility, it's probably better to have

`def fit(self, X, y, **fit_params):  optimal_threshold=fit_params.get('optimal_threshold',0.5) self.regressor_.fit(X, y, **fit_params)`
instead of just `fit(self, X, y, optimal_threshold)`

and for (potentially) better performance

```
y_raw = self.regressor_.fit_predict(X, y, **fit_params)
```

4. add to fit

   ```
   # Check that X and y have correct shape

    X, y = check_X_y(X, y)
   ```
5. add to predict

   ## Check is fit had been called

   check_is_fitted(self)

   ## Input validation

   X = check_array(X)
6. ensure that conformity checks pass, say:

   from sklearn.utils.estimator_checks import check_estimator
   from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

   check_estimator(Thresholder(regressor=LinearRegression()))

And of course, read the [dev guide](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/develop.html), especially if you need setting *random_state*.